# Limit autocompletion of macro function when used as a static extension to multiple types

Tags: autocomplete, macros, expression, haxe, using

When using a static macro function, meant to be used as a static extension, how can I limit types of variables that will get this function on an autocompletion list? Caveat: I know I can use `ExprOf<T>` but I need this for multiple types to check inside my macro if `expr` unifies with a specific abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides leveraging the type system to perform that unification by itself, if possible, you might be able to use a temporary abstract exclusively for this "filtering".

```
// exclusively for static extension x autocomplete
private abstract PseudoType(Dynamic)
  from ActualType1
  from ActualType2
  from ActualType3 {}

[...]

public static macro function myMacro(value:ExprOf<PseudoType>}
{
  // ExprOf doesn't do anything other than help with autocomplete
  // do actual unification here
  // return the appropriate result
}
```

---

[EDIT] here's an example ([live on Try Haxe/alt.](http://try-haxe.mrcdk.com/#7A0d8)):

`Macro.hx`:

```
import haxe.macro.Expr;

private abstract PseudoType(Dynamic)
  from String
  from Int
  from { val:Float } {}

class Macro {
  public static macro function magic(value:ExprOf<PseudoType>)
  {
     return macro Std.string($value);
  }
}
```

`Test.hx`:

```
using Macro;

class Test {
  static function main()
  {
    trace("Haxe is great!".magic());
    trace(42.magic());
    trace({ val : 3.14 }.magic());
  }
}
```

Comment: My problem was that I was expecting autocompletion to pick up `abstract BaseType` when method was accepting `abstract Type from BaseType to BaseType` - had to see your example to understand my mistake. :)